# Facebook Graph Api - Adding new Tab to Page not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the Facebook graph api explorer I am trying to add a new Tab to a fanpage according to the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/).

So I make a **POST** to `/pageId/tabs` with the field `app_id` and my app's ID as value using the page access token I got when querying `userId/accounts`. The access token includes the manage_pages permission.

I get the result `true` which is supposed to mean, the create was successful. But if I run a **GET** on `pageId/tabs` the newly created tab is nowhere to be found.

Am I missing something? Shouldn't it have created the Tab if it says "true"? Has anyone done this and can tell me how it worked for you?

Thanks!

---

I created a [specific bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/112072492280752?browse=search_50751b165758d1233391458)

And [this one](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/194192344040832?browse=search_50751aa36f8507706673949) seems to be related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, so this is a perfect example of how important a meaningful error message or in this case ANY error message at all is.. Dear Facebook API developers, please get your act together, this is just one of many examples of inconsistency!

What the error message should have told me is "**This app is not designed to be added as a tab**" (As btw is the error message when trying to add it with

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL
```

Because when I set the app settings to "tab" instead of "app on facebook", everything works fine! Sigh! Admittedly I could have done this right initially but who is infallible?!

The Graph API call simply should not return `true` if the request fails!

Comment: Yeah, Facebook API and error messages can get quite annoying some times. I especially like the multiple occasions where “an unknown error occurred” is all you’ll get. That looks like just laziness on the API developers side – _if_ an error occurred, you should be able to be more specific on _what exactly_ went wrong …

Comment: 2014 UPDATE -
To add your app as a page tab:
1) go to your app settings, and remove "App On Facebook" platform using the "X" sign in the corner of that box.
2) add you app as a tab (will now work).
3) re-enable the removed platform: in the settings page, click on the "+Add Platform" button on the bottom, choose "App On Facebook" and enter your app's canvas URL(s).

Comment: important addition - you must temporarily remove the "App On Facebook" platform, as explained in my previous comment here, EVEN IF you also have the "Page Tab" platform configured, on the app's settings (as well as "App On Facebook").